# what is the use of coalesce in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to sql server. I googled the use of coalesce and find out it is another words a replace of ISNULL.

I came across a piece of code posted in the [forum](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1521/the-many-uses-of-coalesce-in-sql-server/) about the different uses of coalesce.

```
use adventureworks

DECLARE @DepartmentName VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @DepartmentName = COALESCE(@DepartmentName,'') + Name + ';' 
FROM HumanResources.Department
WHERE (GroupName = 'Executive General and Administration')

SELECT @DepartmentName AS DepartmentNames
```

which return the result in a single line.

So why sql does not support string concatenation by default as in .NET like below?

```
DECLARE @DepartmentName VARCHAR(1000)

    **SELECT @DepartmentName = @DepartmentName + Name + ';'**
    FROM HumanResources.Department
    WHERE (GroupName = 'Executive General and Administration')

    SELECT @DepartmentName AS DepartmentNames
```

what is the use of coalesce in the below line

```
SELECT @DepartmentName = COALESCE(@DepartmentName,'') + Name + ';'
```

and why

```
**SELECT @DepartmentName = @DepartmentName + Name + ';'**
    FROM HumanResources.Department
    WHERE (GroupName = 'Executive General and Administration')
```

is not working?

Comment: generally there are good reasons why NULL plus something results in NULL. it is up to the intelligence of the languauge designer and users of that language to decide exactly what should happen when you combine, NULL, a piece of data that is *unknowable* with a known and specified value 'Department' .  there are lots of arguments for different ways to resolve this, but notablly, SQL actually has two modes 'set concat null yields null' and not...

Comment: notable as well, that Microsoft may be tryng to get rid of this 'dirtiness' , http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx but how they will do that without breaking lots of code and unilaterally deciding for the entire world what the best answer is to this age-old question is TBD.

Comment: @AndyzSmith doesn't seem like a bad decision, you can use isnull or coalesce to do the same thing.

Comment: @Andy right, and how do you suggest we check out and modify thousands of proprietary system's source code that makes use of the global 'set concat yields null', which, according to Microsoft, would actually cause a syntax error now.  crashing my banks ATM.  making me very pissed.  at some computer guy.  who made the wrong decision about mathematical purity about some ridiculous arcane issue.

Comment: why are u using ';' in the following-
`SELECT @DepartmentName = COALESCE(@DepartmentName,'') + Name + ';'`????

Use simply the following-
`SELECT @DepartmentName = COALESCE(@DepartmentName,'') + Name`

Comment: why aren't u using `CONCAT(val1, val2)`?

Comment: @AndyzSmith you don't; the vendor does this, and you don't move the database to a new version of Sql Server until they say its supported.

Comment: @Andy again, not practical.  now you want me to decide whether i want Foobaz feature in SQL Version Umpteenth Million enough to **go back and modify all my old code?** don't make me make that decision.  that's the tool producers job, to make silly decisions like this for me.  and i'm telling you if I tell any superivisor i've ever worked with that we can't do such and such because we can't upgrade to Version 19.1 because of an incompatibility with Null concat yields null i'm gonna get creamed.

Comment: @AndyzSmith yes, that's exactly how software upgrades work.  Bet on some changes.  If you want to upgrade you may have to deal with breaking changes.  You aren't blocked from upgrading you'll need to do work.  That's pretty normal, and you're being warned of the change with plenty of time so you can spread out the analysis and changes.  And quite frankly I don't see what the big deal is about this change; I've never seen this option used or even knew about it until this question, but I've seen plenty uses of isnull and a few of coalesce.  This is pretty normal in the industry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `set @DepartmentName = ''` after `DECLARE @DepartmentName VARCHAR(1000)` and you won't need the coalesce statement.

edit: updated after comment clarified things for me

Comment: this will return only the last column. what i want is concatenated string of all the selected column values.

Answer (score 2):

`coalesce` simply returns the value of **the 1st `non-NULL` argument** in its parameter list.

e.g.

```
1.select coalesce(NULL,0,2,1);
```

will return 0 as **0 doesn't mean NULL**.

```
2.select coalesce(id,emp_id,0) from tab1;
```

In this case attribute-`id` will be returned if it is `NOT NULL` otherwise if `emp_id` is `NOT NULL` `emp_id` will be returned else 0 will be returned.

**In this case for concatenation you can simply use either `+`-operator or `concat()`-function**. But here `coalesce` is used for the case when **`DepartmentName=NULL`** because if you concatenate or do some operation with **`NULL`** the result will be **`NULL`**. Hence to use **blank**(i.e. `''`) in place of `NULL` `coalesce()` has been used.

In this case `coalesce` has been used as `DepartmentName` is `NULL` at the moment when it is declared. Use the syntax **Moho** has given in his answer to substitute the use of `coalesce`.

Comment: ok..so how can i concatenate without coaleasce? I tried  `SELECT @DepartmentName = @DepartmentName + Name + ';'**
    FROM HumanResources.Department
    WHERE (GroupName = 'Executive General and Administration')` but not working

Comment: thanks for providing a better picture of what coalesce does in sql.

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE()` returns the first non-null term. This code:

```
COALESCE(@DepartmentName,'')
```

means return a blank if the department name is null.

Concatenating a `null` with something gives a `null`, so if you don't use `COALESCE()` you'd lose the `name` value too.

Comment: but there is no null records. so it should work even without coalesce right?

Comment: yes - if no nulls, coalesce is useless. maybe it used to be nullable but the schema changed since that code was written.

Comment: then why my second sample of code not working?SELECT DepartmentName = DepartmentName + Name + ';'

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE returns from a list of arguments the first expression that does not evaluate to NULL.

For your example COALESCE(@DepartmentName,'') this means that if #DepartmentName is NULL it shall return '' (an empty string) instead. This is needed because concatenating strings with a null value would return NULL.

SELECT 'test' + NULL  -- will return NULL

[COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: so without coalesce concatenation not possible? I added a piece of code in my post which is not working without coalease. Can you please tell me what wrong in that..